# How to use awk or grep to select data from different lines?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, grep

If I'm in the middle of a script which currently has piped input like this:

```
text sometext moretext text
othertext more somemore futhertext
text sometext moretext text
othertext more somemore futhertext
etc etc (the 2 patterns repeat)
```

and I want to select say the `2nd` column for the first line and the `4th` column for the second line and then pipe the output so I end up with:

```
sometext
furthertext
```

Is there a way to do this? I know that `awk '{print $2}'` and `awk '{print $4}'` exists but how do I make it select different columns on different lines?

Comment: Is there any particular pattern for grabbing the text you want? In other words, is it always the 2nd and 4th columns, or some other alternating way of determining which part to take?

Comment: it's always the 2nd column of a line followed by the 4th column of a line, over and over until the input ends.

Comment: Everything (mostly) is possible. To be able to help you, I guess we need some more input here. Will you have control of the number of lines to process? Will you before running the program know which rows you want to print? If so, of course this is possible, in many different ways. The easiest (and maybe dumbest) would be a bash script, taking a couple of input parameters (number of rows to loop and which column in every row). Pseudo code follows:
For every line in <file/input text>
  Print $column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{split("2 4",a)} NR in a {print $(a[NR])}' file
sometext
futhertext
```

or if you want it to repeat for EVERY 1st and 2nd line:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{n=split("2 4",a)} {print $(a[(NR-1)%n+1])}' file
sometext
futhertext
sometext
futhertext
etc
```

and if you want to do different fields for the 3rd and 4th lines too, it's trivially extensible:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{n=split("2 4 1 3",a)} {print $(a[(NR-1)%n+1])}' file
sometext
futhertext
text
somemore
etc
```

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{print (NR%2 == 0 ? $4 : $2)}' test.txt
```

This uses the [ternary if](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/awk-conditional-statements/) to check for the line number. (`NR` holds the value of the line number.)

Comment: I assumed that you just wanted to do this on an "every other line" basis.

Comment: This can be shortened with `NR%2 ? $2 : $4`

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton.  I did not know that.  I updated my answer to make it portable.

Answer (score 0):

If you like short code, this may solve the problem:

```
awk '{$0=NR%2?$2:$4}1' file
```